# Minimal prime ideals and Hartshorne exercise 1.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Hartshorne exercise 1.8 it is asked to show that if $H=Z(f)$ with $f$ irreducible and $Y$ is an algebraic variety of dimension $r$ the the dimension of each irreducible component of $Y\cap H$ has dimension $r-1$. I have seen solutions to this exercise but I’m not really convinced on an issue. If $C$ is an irreducible component of the intersection then it corresponds to a minimal prime ideal of $A(Y\cap H)=\frac{\mathbb{k}[X_1,\ldots, X_n]}{I(Y\cap H)}$. Since $C$ is an algebraic variety in its own right then $C=Z(\mathfrak{p})$ for some prime $\mathfrak{p}$ and being an irreducible component is to say that the image in $A(Y\cap H)$ is minimal. What I need to show to prove the exercise is that the image of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A(H)$ is still minimal and then apply Krull's Hauptidealsatz (+ some little extra work to show that $f$ is not a unit or a zero divisor in $A(H)$); this is the part that I have not been able to do. Since there is a surjection
$$A(H)\twoheadrightarrow A(Y\cap H)$$
it might be sufficient to show that the preimage of a minimal ideal under a surjective map is minimal but even this I can't do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Just consider the ideal $(f)\subset A(Y)$.

Comment: Is the quotient $\frac{A(Y)}{(f)}$ isomorphic to the coordinate ring of $Y\cap H$?

Comment: Not necessarily (consider $Y=V(y-x^2)$ and $f=y$ inside $\Bbb A^2$), but that doesn't matter - the minimal primes over $(f)$ in $A(Y)$ are the minimal primes over $(I_Y+f)\subset k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ by the correspondence theorem, and height 1 in $A(Y)$ means they're of height one more than $I(Y)$ in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Comment: No! The image of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A(H)$ will not be minimal unless $Y$ is the entire ambient space. To apply the haubtidealsatz though, I think you should look at the ideal of $C$ in $A(Y)$, and argue that it's ideal is minimal with respect to a certain property.